# Task Based service interfaces on azure service bus

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-servicebusrelay

When using net.tcp relay communication in azure we keep getting contract/filter mismatch exceptions on the client.
The problem exists only under these conditions:

- Using azure net.tcp relay binding
- Binding set to Hybid mode (running locally so the services can reach one another)
- The service interface returns Tasks rather than just data contracts

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetData(int value);
}
```

Example service:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Task<string> GetData(int value)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(string.Format("You entered: {0}", value));
    }
}
```

When the bindings switch to Direct connection after a couple of seconds, we start to see contract mismatch exceptions thrown. This is a red herring. I believe what it happening is that the channels are becoming muddled.

Example client usage (note the task continuation that unfortunately doesn’t seem to solve the problem):

```
var relaybinding = new NetTcpRelayBinding();
relaybinding.Security.Mode = EndToEndSecurityMode.None;
relaybinding.ConnectionMode = TcpRelayConnectionMode.Hybrid;

_cf = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(
    relaybinding,
    new EndpointAddress( ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "<<relayservicename>>",     "test")));
_cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior { TokenProvider =     TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("<<policyname>>", "<<token>>") });

return _cf;
var ch = _cf.CreateChannel();

((IChannel)ch).Open();

var result = ch.GetData(10);
var cont = result.ContinueWith(x =>
{
    try
    {
        var r = x.Result;
        ((IChannel)ch).Close();
        return r;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ((IChannel)ch).Abort();
        throw;
    }
}, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

During execution as soon as the relay bindings switch to ‘direct’ mode I start to regularly get contract/filter mismatch exceptions (appended) which I’m pretty sure are a red herring and are actually because I’ve got the wrong channel in my hand on the callback.

I am guessing that the way the nettcprelay binding works under the covers involves some more complex threadpool usage that I haven’t managed to cater for in my calling code. I’ve tried various ways of dealing with the channel , notably by attempting to .ContinueWith synchronously after the call… but to no avail.

Comment: If there is a threading or closure capture problem it is not apparent from the code. Post more complete, but short, code.

Comment: I don't believe its a capture closure problem. Hopefully my code above eliminates that possibility. Which is why I wonder if the problem is perhaps in the NetTcpRelayBinding implementation.